# Including an external html file using a client side scriptng language

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, client-side-scripting

I know how to include files using a server-side scripting language but wanted to know if I could do that using a client-side scripting language? It would be better if it would be Javascript.

Also I want to know if this loading is client side, would it ease any load on the server?

Like I have nav.php and include it with php with the usual `include()` function. I want it done by javascript, i.e. the file should be demanded at the client-side by a call. Is it possible? If yes then How?

Comment: Your question is too abstract. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to include the navigation part of a website from an extrnal file say nav.php... I do it with php... I wanna do it with a client-side language...@NathanRice.. Is it possible or no?? Like I want to call the file includion call from the client?? Possible?

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers have a built-in XMLHttpRequest object to request data from a server.

The XMLHttpRequest object can be used to request data from a web server.

The XMLHttpRequest object is a developers dream, because you can:

- Update a web page without reloading the page
- Request data from a server - after the page has loaded
- Receive data from a server  - after the page has loaded
- Send data to a server - in the background

Visit the following link for more information and an example:
[http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp]